# Radio Button Image Using Picasso (Android)

Tags: android, radio-button

I am creating dynamic radio buttons in Android. The problem is that how to set image at right of the radio button using Picasso library? I search it on google but did not get any solution related to my problem.

Comment: In xml use one linearlayout and add your dynamic radio buttons in that layout.

Comment: Thanks!! @Piyush

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is related to your Layout choice, use `LinearLayout`, put the imageView on the right side of the radio button then,

```
Picasso.with(context)
 .load("YOUR IMAGE URL HERE")        
 .placeholder(DRAWABLE RESOURCE)   // optional        
 .error(DRAWABLE RESOURCE)         // optional        
 .resize(width, height)            // optional        
 .rotate(degree)                   // optional        
 .into(imageView);
```